# Can I use specific numbers to animate human models?

Tags: animation, makehuman

Is it possible to make animations by putting in specific velocity, acceleration into the human character from the numbers I get from human models in Simulation Tools?
The human characters will probably be made through 'makehuman'.

I want to visualize the behavior of human from the numbers I got through engineering simulations.

Comment: Are you asking how to move something at a given speed?

Comment: @Kirbinator Yes, but not in a fixed speed. The speed that changes through time. 
For instance, after running a simulation, the results will come out in numbers. I just want to show them through animation in Blender, since the animation in simulation tool is poor.